# Kivy-ios Xcode build error

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

I'm trying to run my Kivy app in Xcode (5.1). So far, I've managed to create an Xcode project, but it gets weird in build phase, throws an error like so:

```
+ echo '-> Compile to pyo'
-> Compile to pyo
+ /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/tmp/Python-2.7.1/hostpython -OO -m compileall   /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/app-MyApp/YourApp
../tools/populate-project.sh: line 32: /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/tmp/Python-  2.7.1/hostpython: No such file or directory
+ echo '-> Remove unused files (pyc, py)'
-> Remove unused files (pyc, py)
+ find /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/app-MyApp/YourApp -iname '*.py' -exec rm '{}' ';'
+ find /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/app-MyApp/YourApp -iname '*.pyc' -exec rm '{}' ';'
+ echo '-> Source code of MyApp updated.'
-> Source code of MyApp updated.
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Now, most interesting are these lines:

```
+ /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/tmp/Python-2.7.1/hostpython -OO -m compileall   /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/app-MyApp/YourApp
../tools/populate-project.sh: line 32: /Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/tmp/Python-  2.7.1/hostpython: No such file or directory
```

I installed latest version of Python (2.7.6) with 'port' and set it to be default. What I don't understand are:
1. Why it tries to find Python-2.7.1 ???
2. Why it looks in 'kivy-ios/tmp/' folder (I'm sure it's not there, and never was)???

This error comes from 'kivy-ios/populate_project.sh' line 32:

```
echo "-> Compile to pyo"
$HOSTPYTHON -OO -m compileall $YOURAPPDIR
```

and I don't know where '$HOSTPYTHON' is coming from and why it gets evaluated to '/Users/onebit0fme/kivy-ios/tmp/Python-2.7.1/hostpython'.
I'm completely lost and desperate, please help who has at least a hint of what is going on.

UPDATE:
Turns out, when I did 'tools/build-all.sh', it did its job and echoed '**BUILD SUCCEEDED**', but then "tar: Unrecognized archive format". As the result, there's no "build/python/lib/python27.zip" in kivy-ios folder. So, I guess, it didn't finish Kivy-ios installation, again, no idea why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Indeed, turns out kivy-ios did not built all the packages because Python package has been moved to a new location (that's why "tar: Unrecognized archive format" appeared and I ignored it unfortunately). The solution is to change python package http in 'tools/build-python.sh'. 
Here's the link to solution: https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/85